# try to use GDAL to mege geotiff

Tags: python, tiff, gdal, geotiff

I have several consecutive geotiffs that I want to merge .I use GDAL to try out but the final geotiff has no color, only black and white. I want to ask if there is a python plug-in that can directly synthesize multiple Geotiffs.
Or how to use GDAL to synthesize multiple Geotiffs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334933/merging-multiple-bands-together-through-gdal-correctly/52343443#52343443) helps

Answer (score 0):

You can [build a VRT](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html) and check in QGIS if looks like expected. If the VRT is fine then you can [translate](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html) the VRT into TIFF file.

```
gdalbuildvrt _merged.vrt *.tif
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=LZW -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES _merged.vrt _merged.tif
```